# Retrieving an AutoNumber ID that has an alphanumeric format

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

How do I retrieve an ID field that is an AutoNumber and has been given an alphanumeric `Format`, e.g., 'ER001'?

I'm using Access for backend and VB 2010.

My code so far only returns the last number of the ID Column, e.g., `1` instead of `ER001`.

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ID FROM ReqItemList WHERE ReqItem = " & inputin & " "
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the structure of the table ReqItemList? IN which column is stored the value that you are searching?

Comment: The table basically has 3 column the ID(Autonumber Datatype alphanumeric format ),  ReqItem(Text Datatype) and DateReq(Text Datatype). im trying to retrieve the ID using my ReqItem as WHERE.

Comment: SELECT ID FROM ReqItemList WHERE ReqItem = ...

Comment: @Ray sorry mate that's the first thing i did same output thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the confusion here is because the AutoNumber field "has alphanumeric format". If the table design looks like this

[image: DesignView.png]

then the `Format` property `"ER"000` for the ID field will cause it to appear in Access forms and datasheet views as something like `ER001`.

[image: DatasheetView.png]

However, in Design View (the first screenshot) notice that the field is still an Auto**Number** field and its "Field Size" is `Long Integer`. The values themselves are just numbers; they are merely being *formatted* as alphanumeric in the Access user interface.

So the behaviour you are seeing in your VB.NET application is "normal". If you run the query

```vb
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ID FROM ReqItemList WHERE ReqItem=?"
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "foo"
    Dim rtn = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End Using
```

then you will get the Integer value `1`, not the String value `"ER001"`. If you want to have the value appear in your VB.NET forms as `ER001` you will need to apply the formatting in your VB.NET code.

Similarly, if you want to search by ID then you will have to supply the unformatted numeric value. That is

```vb
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ReqItem FROM ReqItemList WHERE ID=?"
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 1
    Dim rtn As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End Using
```

will return `foo`, whereas

```vb
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT ReqItem FROM ReqItemList WHERE ID=?"
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "ER001"
    Dim rtn As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End Using
```

will fail with "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" because ID is really a number, not a text value.

Comment: thanks for all the reply finally understand now what i did wrong